# multiply .mhd images (image and mask) / python

Tags: python, deep-learning, medical-imaging

I want to multiply two images in .mhd format.
(One is the medical image and the other is the desired mask)
But no matter what I search, I can't find the right code.
I would appreciate it if you could guide me, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleITK for this.

Install:

```
$ pip install SimpleITK
```

Sample code:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

# load data
img = sitk.ReadImage("image_file.mhd")
mask = sitk.ReadImage("mask.mhd")

# you can only multiply images with the same voxel type
print("Type (img)  =", img.GetPixelIDTypeAsString())
print("Type (mask) =", mask.GetPixelIDTypeAsString())

# you might need to cast the mask to the image voxel type
# (if they are different)
mask = sitk.Cast(mask, img.GetPixelID())

# now just multiply
output = img * mask
```

It seems like what you might be trying to do is just mask the actual image. If this is the case, you should use the `sitk.Mask` function directly:

```
output = sitk.Mask(img, mask)
```